# iPhone app login issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have an iPhone application which I'm working on and so far i have created a login page for the application such that only the phone's user can access the application. The login works fine and the application works fine, but when i hit the home button, the app is "minimized". And if accessed again from the task switcher it doesn't prompt for a password.

What exactly would be the best way to go about getting the app to request a password. If it helps i use navigation controllers and i have one view dedicated for the login.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How do you store your login credentials? E.g. Did you use NSUserDefaults to save them? Tapping on the home button will only set the app to run in background state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you check app activated in the appdelegate?

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self showLoginWindow];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be working on iOS4. When you hit on Home Button, your app goes into background mode, but still working. So next time, when you open it, it starts exactly from where you left it. Implement the

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

method, to check for login again. Or if you don't want the background processing at all, disable it or use following code

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
   exit(0);
}
```

EDIT -

Don't go for exit(0) approach, simply disable the background processing if you don't want it from info.plist file.

Comment: NOOOOO. Don't disable backgrounding with exit(0); use the `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` key in the info.plist. -0.5

Comment: thanks fluchtpunkt to point out that, I always assumed exit(0); as one of the option. I will keep this in mind now. But off the topic, can you tell me, why we are not supposed to do so?

Comment: now that you ask I don't have a real reason. Imho it's a drastic solution for a problem that doesn't exist (because you can disable backgrounding in the info.plist). Apple says you shouldn't use it because exit(); looks like a crash to the user, but from what I know the app should be in a minimized stage in `appDidEnterBackground` already. But usually disabling backgrounding isn't the answer in the first place. I see it too often for apps that don't have a valid reason to do. Often it's disabled because of "I have this bug but it disappears if I disable backgrounding"

Answer (score 0):

see this [link](http://maniacdev.com/2010/07/screw-multi-tasking-how-to-make-your-ios-4-apps-exit-for-real/)

you need to prevent the app to load from background.

Comment: as I said, the solution for lazy programmers. "Multi-tasking can be great, but it has added some complexity to programming on the iPhone."  lol